# Execute ajax function before location change, status cancelled

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

suppose do some page redirect when click a button:

```
<div onClick="clickButton"></div>

function clickButton(href) {

  // here is an http post request, has no callback or then or done function
  sendSomeRequest()

  location.href = 'https://www.google.com'
}
```

the issue is `trackAjax` request will be cancelled when I see the network, is there a better way to do this instead of `setTimeout`.

also my `sendSomeRequest` has no callback or something like then, it can be seen as a event track function.

Comment: Change the location when the AJAX request resolves. If you have to rewrite `sendSomeRequest()` to support this, then do so

Comment: Nobody can answer this unless you share the contents of `sendSomeRequest`

Comment: it's very simple, a common post request I think, like `$.post("user/track")`,
but not callback or resolve here
i think no genius way to do this, probably just use setTimeout is enough

Answer (score 0):

The best solution would be to edit `sendSomeRequest` to return the [`jqXHR`](http://api.jquery.com/Types/#jqXHR) object created by `$.post()`.

```js
function sendSomeRequest() {
  return $.post('user/track')
}
```

then you can chain your redirect to it

```js
sendSomeRequest().then(() => {
  location.href = 'https://www.google.com'
})
```

---

If you are unable or unwilling to edit `sendSomeRequest()`, you can instead add a global [*"AJAX complete"* handler](https://api.jquery.com/ajaxComplete/).

```js
$(document).ajaxComplete(() => {
  location.href = 'https://www.google.com'
})
sendSomeRequest()
```